# iOS RealmSwift storage with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to use `RealmSwift` in order to save items to the phone storage in Swift 4. I have two different Views; one for the save functionality and another which will display all saved items into a TableView. I have a buildable form coded but i am throwing an error `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` specifically on the line when i call `realm.add`. When i am in my view which is saving, i am using a IBAction with a button to initiate the save functionality. Can anyone help me with this issue? I think the issue is when i set the var of realm however i am unsure.

---

UPDATE:

I have changed my implementation to reflect the idea given in this thread about my original issue. After doing so, when the call to add the item to the realm is called i crash `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` inside the source code of the API. Specifically I crash at this function of the API

```
//CODE EXCERPT FROM REALMSWIFT API 

// Property value from an instance of this object type
id value;
if ([obj isKindOfClass:_info.rlmObjectSchema.objectClass] && 
prop.swiftIvar) {
    if (prop.array) {
        return static_cast<RLMListBase *>(object_getIvar(obj, 
prop.swiftIvar))._rlmArray;
    }
    else { // optional
        value = static_cast<RLMOptionalBase *>(object_getIvar(obj, 
prop.swiftIvar)).underlyingValue; //CRASH OCCURS HERE!!!!!!!!
    }
}
else {
// Property value from some object that's KVC-compatible
    value = RLMValidatedValueForProperty(obj, [obj 
respondsToSelector:prop.getterSel] ? prop.getterName : prop.name,

_info.rlmObjectSchema.className);
}
return value ?: NSNull.null;
```

---

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

var titleOfBook: String?
var author: String?

@IBAction func SavetoFavorites(_ sender: Any) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
guard let realm = try? Realm() else {
  return
}

let newItem = Favorites()
newItem.title = strongSelf.titleOfBook
newItem.author = strongSelf.author

try? realm.write {
  realm.add(newItem) // Crashes on this line
}
}
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

final class Favorites: Object {
var title: String?
var author: String?
}

class FavoritesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var items: Array<Favorites> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: 
"cell")
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, 
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", 
for: indexPath)
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.author
    return cell
}

var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath
    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: You are trying to add an object to the database without first accessing it.

Comment: I thought i was accessing the database with `let realm = try! Realm()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap `realm.add(newItem)` inside a transaction:

```
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(newItem)
}
```

Please note, that write transactions block the thread they are made on so if you're writing big portions of data you should do so on background thread (realm has to be instantiated on that thread too). You could do it like this:

```
@IBAction func saveToFavorites(_ sender: Any) {
  DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    guard let realm = try? Realm() else {
      // avoid force unwrap, optionally report an error
      return
    }

    let newItem = Favorites()
    newItem.title = strongSelf.titleOfBook
    newItem.author = strongSelf.author

    try? realm.write {
      realm.add(newItem)
    }
  }
}
```

Update: I haven't noticed that you have an issue with your model too – since Realm is written with Objective C you should mark your model properties with `@objc dynamic` modifiers:

```
final class Favorites: Object {
  @objc dynamic var title: String?
  @objc dynamic var author: String?
}
```

Comment: How would i go about putting the realm on a different thread? I am now getting an error of `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` which from preliminary research is a thread issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your update. I have reviewed your example to try and understand the logic and i believe i do understand how everything is working. I have added this into the project and i do still receive the same error however, this time in a different spot of the API implementation then previously without this implementation.

Comment: @Alien8tr96 is it related to this question? If so, could you show where's it crashing? And if you're adding objects to realm there, please make sure that you've got it wrapped inside a write transaction as well.

Comment: I have updated my question with the API code where the crash occurs and the current state of my project with the ideas from your solution for my original issue.

Comment: @Alien8tr96 aha, I haven't noticed that your model isn't declared properly. You'll have to add `@objc dynamic` property modifiers as stated in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again! you have been very helpful. I am still getting issues but they are unrelated to this question i believe. Now when i go to save something, the springboard fails and xcode quits. Will have to figure that out.... thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Alien8tr96 BTW, you can check if realm is saving the records by downloading an app container (in XCode open Window -> Devices and Simulators, choose your device/simulator and then your app in the list of Installed Apps, press gear icon and choose "Download Container..."). You then can find realm data file in contents (right click -> Show Package Contents) of the container located at `AppData/Documents/default.realm` path and open it with Realm Browser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I put a break point in my button press to see if it was even hitting that function now and it is except now that i changed the variables to `@objc dynamic` the `DispathQueue` line is hit but then exits the function, no internal code is executed

Comment: @Alien8tr96 that's because internal code is running asynchronously, so you should set a breakpoint on the first line of `DispatchQueue`s internals (i.e. first `guard` statement).

Answer (score 0):

All changes to Realm managed objects (either creation, modification or deletion) need to happen inside write transactions.

```
do {
    try realm.write {
        realm.add(newItem)
    }
} catch {
    //handle error
    print(error)
}
```

For more information, have a look at the [writes section of the official docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes).

Answer (score 0):

Another problem you have in there is that in your `Favorites` class properties are missing `@objc dynamic` attributes. You can read about why you need that in [realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes).

Your code should look like this then:

```
final class Favorites: Object {
  @objc dynamic var title: String?
  @objc dynamic var author: String?
}
```